# Kubernetes service in HostAliases

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have a service name under `hostAliases` in Kubernetes? I want to point a non-existent domain name to a service instead of an IP.

Something like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-name
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        hostAliases:
        - ip: "my-service-name"
          hostnames:
          - "my.domain.com"
```

If not, how would you guys set up a local hosts file entry for a pod to a service? I need to resolve the **non-existent** domain to the service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can not use service name instead of `ip` under `spec.template.spec` in your Deployment definition. 
What you can do, is to get your service IP using `kubectl get services` and use it inside deployment, mapping it to non-existing domain.

The reason why you are not able to use the domain name instead of IP - is that the file /etc/hosts should contain IP and hostnames only. For more information you may want to read this [Creating alias to domain name with /etc/hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58925/creating-alias-to-domain-name-with-etc-hosts) topic.

Comment: Yeah I actually figured out how to inject the CNAME in CoreDNS for Kubernetes. Your explanation is the correct answer so I'll mark it and post my workaround in a bit.

Answer (score 9):

As @VKR explained in the other comment, HostAliases basically just injects into /etc/hosts which only allows for A-record type entries.

For CNAME entries, a workaround is to inject the alias into CoreDNS.

This can be done by editing the ConfirMap for CoreDNS:

```
$ kubectl edit configmap coredns -n kube-system

apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        rewrite name orderer0.example.com orderer0-example-com.orbix-mvp.svc.cluster.local
        rewrite name peer0.example.com peer0-example-com.orbix-mvp.svc.cluster.local
        kubernetes cluster.local {
          pods insecure
          upstream
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        proxy . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
    }
```

I've added the two lines that start with `rewrite name` and once CoreDNS is restarted, the new entries are available throughout the cluster.

CoreDNS can be restarted using the following command:

`kubectl exec -n kube-system coredns-980047985-g2748 -- kill -SIGUSR1 1`

The above needs to be ran for both of the CoreDNS pods.

Comment: Thanks for the trick. One can also restart CoreDNS pods using `kubectl -n kube-system delete pod <coredns_pod_1> <coredns_pod_2>`

Comment: I actually find this way more elegant: `kubectl rollout restart -n kube-system deployment/coredns`

Comment: help for rewrite (substring, regex, etc): https://coredns.io/plugins/rewrite/